# Angular 17 window not defined

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, pre-rendering

Recently after updating my angular cli from 16 to 17 I have been facing performance issues and I had no idea what is SSR and prerendering so I left them enabled. But the root cause was ssr.

- After installing materialize-css I was getting an error M is not defined. Then I imported it from materialize-css.
- Again I was getting an error window is not defined

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I disabled SSR in my angular.json

```
"server": "src/main.server.ts",
            "prerender": true,
            "ssr": {
              "entry": "server.ts"
            }
```

to

```
"server": "src/main.server.ts",
              "prerender": false,
              "ssr": false
```

Answer (score 3):

When using Server side rendering (SSR) and/or prerendering, the app will run on a node environment where the global `window` object isn't defined.

If you want to keep using SSR/prenrender and still access `window` you can use `afterNextRender()` which will be invoked on the browser side only (the callback will be run outside the Angular zone, you also might need `ngZone.run()`.)

Comment: I will give it a try

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same error in Angular 17.

This solution worked for me:

```
if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
   // browser code
}
```

Source: https://dev.to/vvo/how-to-solve-window-is-not-defined-errors-in-react-and-next-js-5f97
Author: Vincent Voyer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and worked around the problem by using ChangeDetectorRef:

```
export class ApplicationLayoutComponent implements OnInit {
  screenWidth!: number;
  injector = inject(Injector);
  @ViewChild('sidebar') sidebar!: ElementRef;

  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])

  onResize(event: Event) {
    this.screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
  }

  constructor(private cd : ChangeDetectorRef) {
    
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    afterNextRender(() => 
      this.changeScreenWidth(),
      {injector: this.injector, phase: AfterRenderPhase.Read}          
    );
  }

  changeScreenWidth() {
    this.screenWidth = window.innerWidth;    
    this.cd.detectChanges();
  }
```