Angular 17 routing for pc and mobile home page
I upgraded from angular 16 to 17 no standalone, then migrated to standalone.
It works fine but I want a cleaner one so I made a new angular 17 project and copied the migrated project. I copied the contents of app-routing.module.ts to app.routes.ts and comments on the NgbModule part. Now I got this error:
10.07.54 [vite] Internal server error: window is not defined
  at eval (C:\Code\bengkel_web_17\src\app\app.routes.ts:27:18)
  at async instantiateModule (file:///C:/Code/bengkel_web_17/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-k5wXcrSr.js:54897:9) (x2)

The code is:
{ path: '', 
  redirectTo:  window.screen.width > 768 ? "home" : "mobile", 
  pathMatch: 'prefix'
}

I am using visual code and in crl+space this window.screen.width is there.
Can anyone help me with what's wrong?

Did you check this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77514292/angular-17-window-not-defined

I tried the suggested answer and have to disabled SSR.

You have SSR enabled, you can either turn it off but the fix for this will be
{ 
    path: '', 
    redirectTo:  window?.screen?.width > 768 ? "home" : "mobile", 
    pathMatch: 'prefix'
}

The fix will only solve this problem, but you should focus only whether you want to you SSR or not!

It's still not working. You are right, SSR is enabled. I have disabled SSR for now cause I need the web up and running. Would like to know if there is a way for SSR enable and have the window function as well.

@rheza555 check if there are other window issue, related fix
